# sed can not work in script file in Windows

Tags: windows, sed

I once write a simple sed command like this

```
s/==/EQU/
```

while I run it in command line:

```
sed 's/==/EQU' filename
```

it works well, replace the '==' with 'EQU', but while I write the command to a script file named `replace.sed`, run it in this way:

```
sed -f replace.sed filename
```

there is a error, says that

```
sed: file replace.sed line 1: unknwon option to 's'
```

What I want to ask is that *is there any problem with my script file replace.sed while it run in windows?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unknown option is almost invariably a rogue character after the trailing `/` (which is missing from your command line version, by the way so it should complain about an unterminated command).

Have a look at you `replace.sed` again. You may have a funny character at the end, which could include the `'` if you forgot to delete it, or even a <kbd>CTRL-M</kbd> DOS-style line ending, though CygWin seems to handle this okay - you haven't specified *which* `sed` you're using (that may help).

---

Okay, based on your edit, it looks like one of my scattergun of suggestions was right :-) You had <kbd>CTRL-M</kbd> at the end of the line because of the CR/LF line endings:

> At the end of each line in the `*.sed` file, there was a `'CR\LF'` pair, and that the problem, but you cannot see it by default, I use notepad to delete them manually and fix the problem. But I have not find a way to delete it automatically or do not contain the `'new-line'` style while edit a new text file in windows.

You may want to get your hands on a more powerful editor like Notepad++ or gVim (my favourite) but, in fact, you *do* have a tool that can get rid of those characters :-) It's called `sed`.

```
sed 's/\015//g' replace.sed >replace2.sed
```

should get rid of all the `CR` characters from your file and give you a `replace2.sed` that you can use for your real job.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and in the code above I missed a '/' at the end of the command. But I finally got the answer. At the end of each line in the *.sed file, there was a 'CR\LF' pair, and that the problem, but you cannot see it by default, I use notepad to delete them manually and fix the problem. But I have not find a way to delete it automatically or do not contain the 'new-line' style while edit a new text file in windows.

Comment: @coaner, see my update. You can actually use `sed` itself to fix your `sed` script :-)

Comment: I find another way to cut these characters at end of line, you and I both use gvim in mswin, so we can add a new command in the vimrc, :set fileformat=unix, then all your newline becomes 'LF' and now sed or other unix origin tool get work. at the end, thanks for you sed-solution, that's wonderful!